# IsNothing() in VS2012 SSRS report causes an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, reporting-services, rdlc

I am making an RDLC report in VS 2012 (ASP.net, C#) and trying to show a yes/no field.  Our test data has nulls in this field, which I want to show as a no.  According to all the research I've found (including SO), the code for this is:

```
=iif( IsNothing(Fields!prior_supplier.Value), "No", iif(Fields!prior_supplier.Value = "Y", "Yes", "No"))
```

(This will appear on the report as: **"Did we use this supplier before? No"**.)

However, the contents of the IsNothing() call keep erroring out.  I have the "failed to compile" indicator in the expression builder, and the result in the report is **#Error**.

How do I fix my IsNothing() expression?  What did I misunderestimatestand?

ETA: Perhaps this has to do with the fact that the expression runs in VB and does not short-circuit?

ETA2: I dropped the field prior_supplier into a textbox just to make sure.  The resulting expression `=Fields!prior_dod_supplier.Value` also failed to compile.  :confused:

Comment: Are you trying to mix VB.NET and C# in the same file?

Comment: Not that I know of.  This expression is inside the RDLC file.

Comment: Haven't worked with SSRS before, but what language is the rest of the RDLC file using?  The equivalent of the above in C# would be something like `=Fields!prior_supplier.Value == null ? "No" : Fields!prior_supplier.Value == "Y" ? "Yes" : "No";`

Comment: If you're using 2010 or later, you could also use the VB [If operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx), which *does* provide short-circuiting - something like this: `=If(IsNothing(Fields!prior_supplier.Value), "No", If(Fields!prior_supplier.Value = "Y", "Yes", "No"))`

Comment: I tested that expression on some sample data, including `NULL` and it worked fine; I wonder if there is some implicit conversion being attempted on your data which is failing. Try replacing `Fields!prior_supplier.Value` in the expression with `CStr(Fields!prior_supplier.Value)` as a test.

Comment: I think `prior_supplier` is nothing, are you making sure `prior_supplier` `IsNot Nothing` before doing this?

Comment: @Tim - the project proper is in C# and ASP.NET.  The RDLC was built with the VS2012 report designer.

Comment: @Hanlet - I am testing whether `prior_supplier` is nothing in this expression.

Comment: More @Tim:  The expression builder does not like `If()`.  This makes me a sad panda.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer I see you test prior_supplier.Value which I assume is a property of prior_supplier...

Comment: @CodeswithHammer - Bummer.  How about this:  `=If IsNothing(Fields!prior_supplier.Value) OrElse Fields!prior_supplier.Value = "N" Then "No" Else "Yes" End If`? `OrElse` will short circuit.

Comment: @IanPreston: CStr() had the same wavy line issue on the field.

Comment: If you are mixing C# and VB in an RDLC report how are you getting your data to start?  Is it coming from a database or entity framework?  You could configure your value in your dataset ahead of time to avoid this issue.  Doing this either in code itself rather than following the wizard or in the database directly or the query.  Just a thought, but this may not work for your situation.

Comment: @djangojazz: The RDLC itself doesn't use C#; I am guessing (based on other SO questions & answers) that *expression* is evaluated using VB.  Though I will attempt the prevailing suggestion of replacing NULLs with N via the query.

Comment: Do you use the wizard to get the report data?  Are you using a query, table, or procedure to get the 'data' that populates the tablix?

Comment: I'm using the query builder to get the report data, and I have a view underlying that.  I'll adjust the view to use `Iif(prior_supplier is null, 'No',Iif(prior_supplier='Y','Yes','No'))` in the relevant field.

Comment: Turning NULL values into 'N' view-side worked; then the report expression was able to turn Y into Yes and N into No.  My view's field: `ISNULL(prior_supplier, 'N') AS prior_supplier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the field in the view to the expression

```
ISNULL(prior_supplier, 'N') AS prior_supplier
```

Then used in the report the expression

```
=iif(Fields!prior_supplier.Value = "Y", "Yes", "No")
```

This solved the #Error issue.